# How to remove certain lines in a text?

Tags: r, text

```
data <- "as follows:\n\n          YEAS--231\n\n     Adams\n     Aguilar\n "
```

I want the line starting with 2 or less blank space, output like this:

```
"as follows:"
```

and remove the lines if they start with 3 or more blank spaces.

```
text <- str_split(data,"\n")
```

The type of "text is list, is there a way to convert "text" to character? Or any other ways to get my result?

Comment: Could you include your expected output in the question?

Comment: I am sorry that I did not press my question clearly. Just made some clarification. Do you have any suggestions? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can split the string on `'\n'` and with `grep` return the strings which has less than 3 spaces at the start of the string.

```
data <- "as follows:\n\n          YEAS--231\n\n     Adams\n     Aguilar\n "
grep('^\\s{3,}', unlist(strsplit(trimws(data), '\n+')), value = TRUE, invert = TRUE)
#[1] "as follows:"
```

---

Using `stringr` functions -

```
library(stringr)
library(magrittr)

str_split(trimws(data), '\\n+') %>%
  unlist() %>%
  str_subset('^\\s{3,}', negate = TRUE)
```

Comment: Use `sapply` to apply it for each value. `df$text1 <- sapply(df$V2, function(x) toString(grep('^\\s{3,}', unlist(strsplit(trimws(x), '\n+')), value = TRUE, invert = TRUE)))`

Answer (score 0):

This is the tidyverse way:

```r
library(tidyverse)
data <- "as follows:\n\n          YEAS--231\n\n     Adams\n     Aguilar\n "
cat(data)
#> as follows:
#> 
#>           YEAS--231
#> 
#>      Adams
#>      Aguilar
#> 

data %>%
  # apply functions on each line
  str_split("\n") %>%
  simplify() %>%
  # lines starting with at least 3 spaces
  discard(~ .x %>% str_starts("[ ]{3}")) %>%
  # empty lines
  discard(~ .x %>% str_trim() == "") %>%
  paste0(collapse = "\n") %>%
  cat()
#> as follows:
```

<sup>Created on 2021-09-26 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: I want to remove the lines if they start with 3 or more blank spaces. Sorry I did not express my question clearly. Any suggestions? Thanks!

Comment: @Foulball I revised my answer